# ElasticSearch: sum weights of all values of certein word and sort accourding it

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch

All documents have these two fields: *a) words* *b) weight of each word.* For example:

Document 1:

```
"text": "word1 word2 word3",  
"weight": [1, 2, 3],
```

Document 2:

```
"text": "word1 word2 word3",  
"weight": [4, 5, 6],
```

Document 3:

```
"text": "word1 word2 word3",  
"weight": [7, 8, 9],
```

If the query is these two words:

```
word1 word2
```

I would like to sum all values of certein word in field **weight** and get result according to the most **weight** field:

```
Document 3 // word1 + word2 = 7+8
Document 2 // word1 + word2 = 4+5
Document 1 // word1 + word2 = 1+2
```

Documents have more than three words, just to simplify the example I poined just three words.

Comment: don't quite understand this meaning：
```
word3 // (7+8)
word2 // (4+5)
word1 // (1+2)
```
Is that what you mean？：
```
Document 3 // (7+8)
Document 2 // (4+5)
Document 1 // (1+2)
```

Comment: caster, thank you! I have edited the post.

Answer (score 0):

This‘s a little difficult, and you may need to modify your storage structure，the index'mappings